# Sequences and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I have the following sequence of functions: $f_n(x) = \frac{x^2 + 4}{2x^2 + (nx + 2)^2}$

How do I show that it converges uniformly on $[1, \infty]$?

I know that I need to show that there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such  that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N$ but I'm not sure how to bound the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

$0 \leq f_n(x) \leq \frac {x^{2}+4} {n^{2}x^{2}} \leq \frac 5 {n^{2}}$ since $\frac {x^{2}+4} {x^{2}}=1+\frac 4 {x^{2}} \leq 1+4 =5$. Hence $f_n \to 0$ uniformly.

Comment: How did you get $f_n(x) \leq \frac{5}{n^2 x^2}$?

Comment: @litopir315 I have edited my answer.